# Order by result of subquery in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

Assuming I have one table `Employees` with the columns `id`, `name`, `salary` and `manager_id`
and another table `fields` with the column `field` which can be any of the fields in the `Employees` table.

How can I sort the employees by the rows in the `fields` table?
For example: when `fields` contains the values `'salary', 'manager_id'`, the employees will be sorted by `salary` and then by `manager_id`.

I tried something like this but it didn't work:

```
SELECT * FROM employees ORDER BY (SELECT field FROM fields)
```

Edit: The original question was a simplified example of my goal.
I want that the employees will be sorted by their super manager id, then by the second super manager id...and in the end by their direct  manager’s id.

Given the employees(id, name, salary, manager_id):
1 Alex 1000 NULL
2 Mor 2000 1
3 John 3000 NULL
4 Chris 4000 1
5 Michael 5000 4
6 Matt 6000 2

The query result will be:
1 Alex 1000 NULL
2 Mor 2000 1
6 Matt 6000 2
4 Chris 4000 1
5 Michael 5000 4
3 John 3000 NULL

Comment: @semicolon this is not correct, how do you imagine this join should looks like? table fields contain field names

Comment: Add some sample table data and the expected result - as formatted text (not images.)

Comment: @Livius question was edited post comment. Now i get it.

Comment: @semicolon ok, this is living question ;-). `sitoNz` - Question is quite interesting, but is your design ok? I never have such problem and i suppose most of us. What is the purpose of storing this sorting info in the table?

Comment: If there is any feature in PostgreSQL to transpose rows to column(like in SQL Server) then you can go with it.

Comment: "If there is any feature in PostgreSQL to transpose rows to column(like in SQL Server) then you can go with it." PostgreSQL supports `crosstab` @semicolon

Comment: Question is unclear can you post the CREATE TABLE statement(s) and INSERTs for the data for every table involved in this question? And formatted expected results?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do that in a single query.

First you have to query `fields`, then construct an SQL statement with the proper `ORDER BY` clause and run that.

Beware of SQL injection — use the [`format`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-FORMAT) function to construct the query.

Answer (score 0):

If you can tell us the error that it gives you it may help us helping you

what i think is that `'` symbols are what making the issue so it will be as if you're writing:

```
SELECT * FROM employees ORDER BY 'salary', 'parent_id'
```

try replacing it with a blank character using `Replace()`

Comment: I tried ORDER BY replace(original subquery, ’’’’, ’’). Is that what you mean? When there is only one row in the fields table the query result is the same as the result without ORDER BY clause, and when there is more than one row the error is “more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression”

Answer (score 0):

There is a way how this can be accomplished. But i strongly advice to change your design.
To support this you must add `SEQ` field in your `Fields` table to decide order of fields in `Fields` table. First field have SEQ 1, second 2 ...

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    Employees E
ORDER BY
    CASE 
    (SELECT
        F.NAME
    FROM
        Fields F ORDER BY F.SEQ LIMIT 1) 
    WHEN 'salary' THEN E.salary
    WHEN 'parent_id' THEN E.parent_id
    ELSE 0 END

    ,
    CASE 
    (SELECT
        F.NAME
    FROM
        Fields F ORDER BY F.SEQ LIMIT 1 OFFSET 1) 
    WHEN 'salary' THEN E.salary
    WHEN 'parent_id' THEN E.parent_id
    ELSE 0 END
```

sample on sql fiddle to demonstrate. There are two tables `FieldsA` and `FieldsB` to make testing easier without need for delete from table Fields and new records to see if it is working. 
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/64df6e/2/0

Comment: The problem is that I have to change the query for every column I add to the employees table and when there are many columns the query will be huge

Comment: then only way is to create stored procedure and build your sql dynammicaly https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-EXECUTING-DYN